# Global RegEx Replace Function to Create Html from Square Brackets []

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, global, ektron

I have some existing code that looks something like this:

```
[tag:cb cbid="12345" cbwidth="200" cbclassname="calloutbox" cbposition="left"] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
[tag:cb cbid="123" cbwidth="200" cbclass="calloutbox2" cbposition="left"] Suspendisse eleifend enim a magna pretium porttitor.
```

I need to write a VB .Net global function that will match these `[tag:cb]` and take the optional parameters and rewrite the string with Html  tags.

```
<div id="12345" width="200" class="calloutbox" position="left">content (based on id)</div>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Care to explain a little bit more? It is unclear to me how you are planning to go from A to B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
^\[tag:cb([^\]]*)\](.*)$
```

And then you use capturegroup 1 and 2 to make the new string:

```
<div$1>$2</div>
```

This will generate something like:

```
<div cbid="12345" cbwidth="200" cbclassname="calloutbox" cbposition="left"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<div cbid="123" cbwidth="200" cbclass="calloutbox2" cbposition="left"> Suspendisse eleifend enim a magna pretium porttitor.</div>
```

The problem is that it will still have attributes like `cbid="123"` instead of `id="123"`. Preferably you would like to run it through another regexp to replace all occurances of `cb([^=]*)` and replace with capturegroup 1.

That would output the following:

```
<div id="12345" width="200" classname="calloutbox" position="left"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
<div id="123" width="200" class="calloutbox2" position="left"> Suspendisse eleifend enim a magna pretium porttitor.</div>
```

All you have to do now is to implement it in VB .Net :)

You can see the first part in action here: http://regexr.com?2vbkq 
and the second part here: http://regexr.com?2vbl3